# Salt = Sodium Chloride, for this question

Tags: discussion

I think it should be clarified in [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/415/is-salt-white-death) that the salt generally being referred to is sodium chloride. However, the human body requirements for salt may be more than just sodium chloride, so it may affect the context of some of the answers (eg [one commenter says](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/6347/5343) they eat salt to avoid cramp. I've heard of magnesium salts being used for this instead!). Any suggestions (or volunteers!) on how to tidy this up?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking to the general public, salt means sodium chloride. Everyone understands what is meant by it and there is no need to use the exact chemical term in this case, I think.